# Retrieving next request date and associated ID for UNNotificationRequest

Tags: swift, xcode, triggers, min, unnotificationrequest

Update:

I needed to find the next notification request and the associated ID so I ended up going with this:

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests {
        (requests) in
        var requestDates = [String:Date]()
        for request in requests{
            let requestId = request.identifier
            let trigger = request.trigger as! UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
            let triggerDate = trigger.nextTriggerDate()
            requestDates[requestId] = triggerDate
        }

        let nextRequest = requestDates.min{ a, b in a.value < b.value }
        print(String(describing: nextRequest))

        }
```

I thought that this method might provide a more elegant solution but as Duncan pointed out below UNNotificationRequests are not comparable:

```
requests.min(by: (UNNotificationRequest, UNNotificationRequest) throws -> Bool>)
```

If anyone has a better solution then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `Sequence` has a `min()` function for sequences of objects that conform to the `Comparable` protocol. I don't think `UNNotificationRequest` objects are comparable, so you can't use `min()` on an array of `UNNotificationRequest` objects directly.

You'd have to first use flatMap to convert your array of notifications to an array of non-nil trigger Dates:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
    //map the array of `UNNotificationRequest`s to their 
    //trigger Dates and discard any that don't have a trigger date
    guard let firstTriggerDate = (requests.flatMap { 
       $0.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
       .nextTriggerDate()
    }).min() else { return } 
    print(firstTriggerDate)
}
```

(That code might need a little adjustment to make it compile, but it's the basic idea.)

Comment: Thanks, I needed the identifier associated with the date so I ended up going with a dict to store the information and ran the min method on that.